# How to run a script in multiple instances ? ( Ubuntu server )

Tags: bash, shell-script, parallelism

How can I run a script in multiple instances in Ubuntu server?

For example, I have a long running script named `scanner.sh` placed in `/usr/bin/`,  which I wish to run the script in 10 parallel instances. How can I start the parallel tasks (and pass different flags / options / parameters to them)?

and how can I stop the instances?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#**parallel_scaller.sh**
# Script to async run scanner.sh
# USAGE: $> bash parallel_scanner.sh "FLAGS FOR INSTANCE 1" ... "FLAGS FOR INSTANCES 10"
$1=`echo $1 | sed 's/"//g'`
$2=`echo $1 | sed 's/"//g'`
$3=`echo $1 | sed 's/"//g'`
$4=`echo $1 | sed 's/"//g'`
$5=`echo $1 | sed 's/"//g'`
$6=`echo $1 | sed 's/"//g'`
$7=`echo $1 | sed 's/"//g'`
$8=`echo $1 | sed 's/"//g'`
$9=`echo $1 | sed 's/"//g'`
$10=`echo $1 | sed 's/"//g'`

bash scanner& $1 2>&1
bash scanner& $2 2>&1
bash scanner& $3 2>&1
bash scanner& $4 2>&1 
bash scanner& $5 2>&1
bash scanner& $6 2>&1
bash scanner& $7 2>&1
bash scanner& $8 2>&1
bash scanner& $9 2>&1
bash scanner& $10 2>&1
```

& places task in background.
2>&1 redirects STDERR(2) to STDOUT(1).

To end the processes, type:

```
$> ps aux | grep scanner
$> kill $PIDS
```

Comment: Thanks. But how to stop specific instance? Also, the lines below should be: `bash scanner.sh $1 2>&1`, right ?

Answer (score 2):

Using GNU Parallel it looks like this:

```
parallel scanner {} ::: "--flags --for --instance 1" "--for 2" "--for 3"
```

It will spawn one job per CPU. To stop simply press CTRL-C.

GNU Parallel is a general parallelizer and makes is easy to run jobs in parallel on the same machine or on multiple machines you have ssh access to. It can often replace a `for` loop.

If you have 32 different jobs you want to run on 4 CPUs, a straight forward way to parallelize is to run 8 jobs on each CPU:

[image: Simple scheduling]

GNU Parallel instead spawns a new process when one finishes - keeping the CPUs active and thus saving time:

[image: GNU Parallel scheduling]

**Installation**

If GNU Parallel is not packaged for your distribution, you can do a personal installation, which does not require root access. It can be done in 10 seconds by doing this:

```
$ (wget -O - pi.dk/3 || lynx -source pi.dk/3 || curl pi.dk/3/ || \
   fetch -o - http://pi.dk/3 ) > install.sh
$ sha1sum install.sh | grep 883c667e01eed62f975ad28b6d50e22a
12345678 883c667e 01eed62f 975ad28b 6d50e22a
$ md5sum install.sh | grep cc21b4c943fd03e93ae1ae49e28573c0
cc21b4c9 43fd03e9 3ae1ae49 e28573c0
$ sha512sum install.sh | grep da012ec113b49a54e705f86d51e784ebced224fdf
79945d9d 250b42a4 2067bb00 99da012e c113b49a 54e705f8 6d51e784 ebced224
fdff3f52 ca588d64 e75f6033 61bd543f d631f592 2f87ceb2 ab034149 6df84a35
$ bash install.sh
```

For other installation options see http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/parallel.git/tree/README

**Learn more**

See more examples: http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html

Watch the intro videos: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL284C9FF2488BC6D1

Walk through the tutorial: http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/parallel_tutorial.html

Sign up for the email list to get support: https://lists.gnu.org/mailman/listinfo/parallel

Comment: That was very clear and helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to propose you start using configuration management system like, preferrably Ansible.

It's written on Python, really easy-to-use for everyone, for newbies also.

Follow the docs http://docs.ansible.com/ and get started!

Answer (score 0):

Besides the suggested answer, I use the following command:

```
nohup ./scanner.py -flag1 flag1value -flag2 flag2value &
```

to create a new instance. To view all running `scanner.py` instance, I use:

```
ps aux | grep scanner.py
```

To kill a specific instance, I use:

```
kill -9 {PID}
```

where `{PID}` is obtained from the `ps aux` command, e.g. `kill -9 1234`